# React native redux clear cart after checkout

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

After a user checks out successfully, I want to clear the cart. Currently, when user checks out and goes back to main screen the items are still in their cart.

Reducers file:

```
let defaultState = {
// orders with cafeName as Key and list of items as a value
selectedItems: { items: [] },
};

let cartReducer = (state = defaultState, action) => {
 switch (action.type) {
   case "ADD_TO_CART": {
   let newState = { ...state };
   cafeName = action.payload.cafeName;

  if (action.payload.checkboxValue) {
    console.log("ADD TO CART");

    newState.selectedItems = {
      items: [...newState.selectedItems.items, action.payload],
    };
  } else {
    console.log("REMOVE FROM CART");
    newState.selectedItems = {
      items: [
        ...newState.selectedItems.items.filter(
          (item) => item.name !== action.payload.name
        ),
      ],
    };
  }

  console.log(newState);
  return newState;
 }

  default:
    return state;
   }
  };

  export default cartReducer;
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can just clear your cart by making new action type and add it to the reducer

```
CLEAR_CART
```

in reducer, just return default state which is empty cart

```
...
case 'CLEAR_CART':
  return defaultState
...
```

and by dispatching it after user finished checked out, will do this CLEAR_CART action

---

try check reduxToolkit https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/quick-start#create-a-redux-state-slice as well for simpler writings of redux actions and reducers